# Clean method to upgrade NestJS

Tags: typescript, npm, nestjs

I will upgrade my NestJS project from v5 to v6. What is the clean methods to do that. Did I need create a new V6 project or can I upgrade dependencies ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I create a new directory, /server/nestjs6, and use the Nestjs cli to install the new version of Nestjs in that.  Then I copy my code from /server/nestjs5 to nestjs6 and 'npm run start'.  Of course shut down the nestjs5 server first.

Now you'll get errors but have a list of dependencies you need to install so go through that process until Nestjs boots up and you have happy code.

See the installation and migration sections of the docs.

After a while you can delete /nestjs5.  Nice to have a backup for a few weeks.